# Ajax support in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

We are just starting a new web application using Spring MVC 3.0.

We will be using lot of Ajax in our application. I wanted to know if there is any in built support for Ajax (like Struts 2) in Spring MVC 3.0 or do we have to use some third party API like DWR or jQuery?

We have used lot of both DWR and jQuery in our other applications based on Struts 1 and Struts 2. So, we are very familiar with both of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring mvc 3 supports Ajax. Check [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what is the better option to use Ajax with Spring 3 MVC? Will this in built support enough for all the ajax needs?

Comment: I have worked with Spring MVC 3 and JSON. Works well for me. But depends what you want to do. Your original question was whether Spring MVC 3 supported Ajax, for that the answer is yes but for what you have asked above only you can decide after going thru the samples.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the link in Viren Pushpanayagam's answer, the typical way to use ajax with Spring is to use JQuery (or plain JS or other framework, it doesn't matter) to make ajax call, passing necessary parameters. Spring controller handles request and returns JSON (which is very simple in Spring if you just annotate your controller with @ResponseBody and include Jackson Mapper or Gson in your classpath). There is no Spring tag library or other feature that performs the ajax functionality that I am aware of.